# URL issue with tomcat include project name

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting

I am using Eclipse for J2EE project... 
one device send request to my side and url like

```
http://myIP:myPort/corporationweb/Controller
```

`/corporationweb/Controller` is fixed we can't change it because it made on device

my project name in eclipse is "`VirtualTest`" but here tomcat include project name if i mapping any servlet, `/corporationweb/Controller` URL  like

```
http://localhost:8080/VirtualTest/corporationweb/Controller
```

I need page open without change project name

- any i can mapping servlet directly so URL like `http://localhost:8080/corporationweb/Controller`
- any URL rewriting technique..
- make as default application for my project

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rightclick project in Eclipse, choose *Properties*, go to *Web Project Settings* and set *Context root* to `/`.

[image]

This will let Eclipse deploy the project on context root instead of project name (which is the default).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you really need to ensure that your application is written the way so that it *does not care* on which context path the application is been deployed. This is namely a server specific setting which is not controllable from inside your project. Make use of [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) the smart way.

Comment: Probably would help to somebody. After change the Context root, do clean and publish to let server knows about your changes.

Comment: Do not work well for me _(Eclipse long responds and hangs on apply - may be something goes wrong in my environment)_ The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665245/deploy-webapp-from-eclipse-to-tomcat-root-context solution works better in my case

Comment: I have no such and option "Web Project Settings"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make "VirtualTest" as default application for your project, and not showing this name in URL, you can simply change project name to "root", which is a special name for the default application.
Your URL will be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/corporationweb/Controller
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse. Go to server and remove the unwanted project which are Synchronized, then restart your server. Worked for me