# How to Remove Project name from eclipse url?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Basically I want to remove project name while I access my project in eclipse.

so currently when I want to access a link of my web-app I have to put it as `localhost:8080/project_name/blah_blah_blah`
But I want it accessible by just `localhost:8080/blah_blah_blah`
 or say The project itself should be accessible by just `localhost:8080`
.

Through googling I found this [URL issue with tomcat include project name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160241/url-issue-with-tomcat-include-project-name) but in my case my context root is as `/` by default.

[Project Context root Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lfyt.png)

FYI: This is the only project I have in my Eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For people who come across this problem too.

To explain deeply: First remember that eclipse uses server under eclipse `project explorer` within its all configuration.

In order for you change your project path to something different, what you can do is to open `server.xml` under `Project Explorer -> Servers -> Tomcat vX.X ... -> server.xml`.

At the bottom of this file You should see this line Before End of `</host` Tag:

`<Context docBase="Duck" path="/Duck" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Duck"/>`

**Notice**: My project Name is `Duck`.

Now in order for you to access your web-app without project name replace `path="/Duck"` to just `path="/"` or You can set it to any name you want.

Comment: Perfect! from the Servers folder in the left pane of eclipse