# Apache Tomcat 7 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm getting an error in my browser when trying to run a servlet. It says

> The requested resource is not available.

and

> "HTTP Status 404-". The console doesn't print any errors but one
>   warning: " [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
>   Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CDM' did not
>   find a matching property."

It feels like I've tried everything to get it to work so I'm open to any suggestion that will make my code work.

**StudentResultRegistered.java**

```
package com.cdm;


import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;




@WebServlet(name="studentResultRegistered",urlPatterns={"/herpDerp"})
public class StudentResultRegistered extends HttpServlet {



    @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String s=request.getParameter("studentID");  
    String k=request.getParameter("kursKod");  
    String t=request.getParameter("termin");  
    String p=request.getParameter("provNr"); 
    String b=request.getParameter("betyg"); 



    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school_server", "testuser", "testuser");



        String sql = "INSERT INTO regStudentResult (studentID, kursKod, termin, provNr, betyg)" +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1,s);  
        ps.setString(2,k);  
        ps.setString(3,t);  
        ps.setString(4,p);
        ps.setString(5,b);

        int i=ps.executeUpdate();  
        if(i>0)  
        out.print("success");  
    }catch (Exception e2) {System.out.println(e2);}  

    out.close();  
    } 


}//studentResultRegistered
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Course Data Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Registrera Resultat</h1>

<FORM ACTION="/studentResultRegistered" method="get">
  StudentID:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="studentID" VALUE=""><BR>

  Kurskod:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="kursKod" VALUE=""><BR>

  Termin:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="termin" VALUE=""><BR>

  ProvNr:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="provNr" VALUE=""><BR>

  Betyg:
  <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="betyg" VALUE=""><BR>


    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Registrera Resultat">
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>CDM</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>



 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>studentResultRegistered</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cdm;</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>studentResultRegistered</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/herpDerp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: What URL do you load in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost/CDM/WEB-INF/index.html

Comment: nevertheless remove the ;(semicolon) in <servlet-class>

Comment: removed it, and it didn't improve my error

Comment: did you debug it line by line? does it run until the end ? if not at which line does it break ?

Comment: I'm not very good with debugging, but as far as I'm concerned, it runs all the way through

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a full class name not just a package:

```
<servlet-class>com.cdm.StudentResultRegistered</servlet-class>
```

#### EDIT:

Additional problems to be fixed:

1. index.html should be placed in the web folder (parent of WEB-INF)
2. should be accessed as `http://localhost/index.html` or `http://localhost/CDM/index.html` depending on how the web context is configured (see [deploy webapp from Eclipse to Tomcat root context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665245/deploy-webapp-from-eclipse-to-tomcat-root-context)). Note that index.html is not required in the url, as it is already specified as a default page in web.xml
3. Action form url should match the servlet path - not the servlet name.

Comment: changed it, no difference same error:(

Comment: Are you getting the error on clicking submit? Your form action should match the url /herpDerp  - not the servlet name

Comment: I don't get as far as seeing my form due to the "The requested resource is not available."-error. I.e. I get the error when trying to run the servlet from the beginning

Comment: I see, this message is about not being able to find your index.html resource. I assume your tomcat runs on port 80. You need to put index.html inside web directory (parent of WEB-INF). Then try http://localhost/CDM/index.html. Also if that does not work try http://localhost/index.html

Comment: you, sir or madam, just saved my sanity! thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to fix your form action as I mentioned above, and mark the answer accepted if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks alot, I had my index.jsp inside web-inf folder

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your comment saying the URL in your browser is

```
localhost/CDM/WEB-INF/index.html
```

WEB-INF is a hidden directory - Tomcat (or any other Servlet container) will never serve content from that directory, it should contain confirguation, classes and jars.

Your index.html file should be in the application root (in CDM directory) and your URL should be

```
localhost/CDM/index.html
```