# Home button for all level of url in java application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I have made my application to run as root in tomcat using  [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665245/deploy-webapp-from-eclipse-to-tomcat-root-context).

Now my application coming in browser as `http://localhost:8080/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/myApp/` **As i Expected**.

I have single menubar at the top which is same for every page using `<%@include file="/jsp/header.jsp"  %>`

There is home button what will bring user to the home page from any level of url like `http://localhost:8080/a` `http://localhost:8080/a/b/c` all to `http://localhost:8080/`.

before making my app root i was using

```
<a class="...." href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">Home</a>
```

But now `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` value is and empty string()
. so the generate html is

```
<a href="" class="...."></a>
```

Which is only reloading the current page when clicked.
What should i do to make it work like before. And i would like to make it server independent (now it is in local host some day it will go to a real serve i hope).

Comment: if every body think this question is not worthy enough,then  i can delete this as it  has  very easy solution which is give by @fd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a `/` character and have the URL work in both cases.

```
<a class="...." href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Home</a>
```

Comment: well that worked .. i am thinking of my self a dumb and stupid because of not trying that. By the way thanks.