# How to access http://localhost:8080/pdf/abc123.pdf tomcat eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I my code I am trying to access the file abc123.pdf like 
http://localhost:8080/pdf/abc123.pdf . I have set up the the project in eclipse and takes the control of tomcat installation .My project is present under C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.45\wtpwebapps\ . How can access the file abc123.pdf where shall i keep it so that it can be accessed by http://localhost:8080/pdf/abc123.pdf

Comment: with some code...

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the webapp as root webapp, see:
[deploy webapp from Eclipse to Tomcat root context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665245/deploy-webapp-from-eclipse-to-tomcat-root-context)

Resources that should be accessable directly have to be in the `web`-folder of your project. Something like this:

```
C:\[PATH_TO_WORKSPACE]\[WEBAPPNAME]\web\pdf\abc123.pdf
```

After deployment it should be here:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.45\wtpwebapps\[WEBAPPNAME]\pdf\abc123.pdf
```

Comment: \pdf\abc123.pdf will be on local path like C:/users/pdf
However I want to access it over http protocall
like  http://localhost:8080/pdf/abc123.pdf

Comment: If you don't want the pdf in your project, you can write a servlet that reads the file with a FileInputStream and returns the byte stream to the user (with appropriate HTTP headers).

Comment: how can I do it like below
 <Context  docBase="C:/Users/" path="/pdf/" />

I dont want to write Servlet

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the file in your tomcat
2. write this file to HttpServletResponse
3. only support the GET method
4. when browser get this response which with byte stream in ResponseBody it will start to download